# Cannot match the requested parameter with Database entries [ Spring MVC and Hibernate ORM ]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am new to Spring and Hibernate
I am trying to add login functionality to my web app. I made a form and tried to read the form like this,

```
@Autowired
public UserDAO userList; 

@RequestMapping(value="index/login/result" , params="go")
public String Authenticate(@RequestParam("Username") String name,
        @RequestParam("Password") String password,
        Model theModel){
    
   List<User> users= userList.getUsers();
   for(User x:users){
       if(x.getUsername().equals(name)&&x.getPassword().equals(password)){
           return "success"; //proceeds to next page
       }
       
   }
   
   return "index"; // returns to home page
}
```

But nothing works, it never enters the if block and i have confirmed that the values of x.getUsername() and x.getPassword() matches name and password respectively.I am able to successfully read the database so i think nothing is wrong with my DAO.I am using Eclipse with Tomcat 8 and mysql. I dont know where i am going wrong.

## Edit1

I solved the problem but I still cannot figure out the cause of the problem. I changed the if condition like this ,

```
if(x.getUsername().equals(name.trim())&&x.getPassword().equals(password.trim()))
```

I compared the hashcodes of both x.getUsername() and (name) and they turned out to be different,even when both the string look identical. So I used trim method to remove the whitespaces. So can anyone tell me what caused the variation in the hashcodes of these strings.

Comment: the problem is you can successfully find the user with given name and password, but you cannot redirect to success page?

Comment: Did you verify if the users List is containing any users at all? The UserDAO class is a spring component right?

Answer (score 0):

There could be two problems that I can think of:

1. Unable to access success.jsp.
2. If condition not satisfied.

If it is the problem of "if" condition then index.jsp would be returned. So atleast you should be able to see either of jsp's.

If success.jsp is unreachable check it is in the same folder as that of "index".

If none of the jsp's are accessible check your dispatcher-servlet and make sure you have declared the base package coorectly.

Answer (score 0):

As you have stated in your edit, the strings were not identical as the ones received from the frontend contained whitespace, but the ones saved in the DB did not.

One possible reason for this situation could be that when the user registered, username and password where entered without any leading or trailing spaces and these values were persisted in the database.
Now when the user wants to login, she might unintenionally add a space after the username or password, resulting in strings containing whitespace that are processed in your controller.

If you have a look at the [String::hashCode() implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.hashCode%28%29), you'll notice
that whitespace is not handled in a special way compared to visible characters.
The same applies for the [String::equals() implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

So as both Java's hashCode() and equals() implementation take whitespace into account, hashCode() returned different results and equals() returned false when username/password were compared.

By using trim(), trailing and leading whitespace has been removed from the data received from the client, so that they are now equal to the data that is persisted in your DB.

You should consider always normalizing the data (i.e. removing irrelevant whitespace) if it has been received from the client.

Comment: Can you give a reason why the string received from the  frontend contained the whitespaces while the string received from the database did not... Does this happen always or is there any particular situaton in which this problem occurs?

Comment: @kakashi I have added a possible reason as the second paragraph